# Are there any similar statements from scriptures that reject "setting up of religious standards"?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, other-religions, yudhisthira

Consider the following question and answer from the scripture named Mahabharatha

> The Yaksha asked,--'... what is hypocrisy?...
>
> Yudhishthira answered,--'... The setting up of a religious standard is
> hypocrisy...
>
> [[Section 311, Aranya Parva, Vana Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03311.htm)

Yudhishthira clearly says that setting up a religious standard is not encouraged. It is a great statement and broadly applicable.

Are there any similar statements from scriptures of Sanathan dharma that are against setting up a religious standard?

Comment: Can you please explain what or how you exactly interpret the meaning of"religious standards" to be?

Comment: @Vivikta as a set of rules.

Comment: without context these 4 word english phrases are prone to misinterpretation. if i recall, the correct question is 'what is Dambha', and yudhishtir's reply is 'acting as if one is religious in public but secretly not following those in private', or 'showing off one's religious piety'

Comment: @mar Maybe true, but people who know Sanskrit can correct it.

Comment: if everyone on this site makes it a point to post original sanskrit verse along with english translation, that would make lives much easier.

Comment: @mar Yeah. I will try. Sanskrit Stack Exchange may be a help for us. But it failed at least 2 times due to less activity.

Comment: u just need to get the sanskrit version of that verse from online pdfs and copy-paste here

Comment: Ha @mar, I will try. Need to search a lot.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, the translation might have been wrongly interpreted.

So, I doubt in the light of that, does the question stands answerable?

In any case, let's see the original Sanskrit Text, along with its [Translated version by Gita Press Gorakhpur](https://archive.org/details/mahabharata02ramauoft/page/974/mode/2up), translated into Hindi by Ramanarayanadatta Astri

> यक्ष उवाच
>
> कोऽहङ्कार इति प्रोक्तः कश्च दम्भः प्रकीर्तितः ।  किं तद् दैवं परं
> प्रोक्तं किं तत् पैशुन्यमुच्यते ॥ ९९ ॥
>
> [Hindi Translation]:
>
> यक्षने पूछा - अहङ्कार किसे कहते हैं ? दम्भ क्या कहलाता है ? जिसे परम
> दैव कहते हैं, वह क्या है ? और पैशुन्य किसका नाम है ? ॥ ९९ ॥
>
> English Translation by Self
>
> > The Yaksha asked-
>
> > 99. **What is pride (ego)? What is deceitful hypocrisy (cheating, fraud)? What is known as the supreme godsend gift? And what is to be
> >     known as wickedness (depravity)?**

---

And Yudhishthira replies to this -

> युधिष्ठिर उवाच ।
>
> महाज्ञानमहङ्कारो दम्भो धर्मो ध्वजोच्छ्रयः । दैवं दानफलं प्रोक्तं
> पैशुन्यं परदूषणम् ॥ १० ॥
>
> [Hindi Translation]:
>
> युधिष्ठिर बोले - महान् अज्ञान अहङ्कार है, अपने को झूठ-मूठ बड़ा
> धर्मात्मा प्रसिद्ध करना दम्भ है, दान का फल दैव कहलाता है और दूसरों को
> दोष लगाना पैशुन्य (चुगली) है ॥ १०० ॥
>
> English Translation by Self
>
> > 100. The great stolid ignorance is Pride. **Falsely proclaiming oneself as the greatest of the righteous person is to be known as
> >      hypocrisy.** God's grace is the fruit of our charitable gifts and
> >      finding faults in others is to be known as wickedness!

For, further clarification, here's [M.N. Dutt's Translation](https://archive.org/details/TheMahabharataMNDutt/page/n885/mode/2up) of the same verse

> The Yaksha said:-
>
> > 99. What is spoken of as pride? What is it that is called hypocrisy? What is said to be the grace of the gods? And what is called
> >     wickedness?
>
> Yudhisthira said:-
>
> > 100. Pride consists in stolid ignorance. **What is called hypocrisy is the setting up (false show) of the banner of religion.** The fruit of
> >      charity is divine gift. And wicked ness consists in slandering others.

---

So, Yuddhisthira doesn't talk about anything against the setting of the "religious-standards" as interpreted by the OP. Rather, the use of the term hypocrisy is denoted - *Falsely proclaiming oneself as the greatest of the righteous person*

i.e, "setting up (false show) of the banner of religion" or "using dharma merely as an insignia" has been termed hypocrisy by Yudhishthira.

Therefore, in the lieu of the above re-interpretation, the question stands unanswerable as asked.

If it's reworded as per the answer given by Yuddhisthira, then being a hypocrite are condemned in several texts. For instance - [B.G. 3.6](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=3&field_nsutra_value=6&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&etpurohit=1&etgb=1&setgb=1&etssa=1&etassa=1&etradi=1&etadi=1), and [**BG 16.4**](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=16&field_nsutra_value=4&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&choose=1), and [Manu Smriti 4.30](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200132.html), etc..

Comment: Are you good at Sanskrit?

Comment: Well, personally, I don't like to rely much on my Sanskrit knowledge, whatever may I have. But, the above two translations by two extremely knowledgeable people (MN. Dutt and the Gita Press Translations) makes it abundantly clear that the translated version by K.M Ganguli has been misinterpreted/oversighted error, doesn't it? @Hanugm  :)) I hope my answer helped clear the doubt! :)